# How to get custom response header in angular 2?

Tags: http, angular, observable

I am new to angular 2 and currently working with angular 2.2.1 in which I am successfully able to post request and get success response however when I try to get **Authorization** header from response I always get null whether I am able to get **Content-Type** header. Below is my solution so far.

**service.ts login method:**

```
login(model: LoginModel) {
        let requestUrl = '/someurl';
        let requestPayload = JSON.stringify(model);
        let headers = this.getHeaders(false); // ... Set all required headers       

        let options = new RequestOptions({ headers: headers }); // Create a request option

        return this.http.post(requestUrl, requestPayload, options) // ...using post request
            //.map((res: Response)) // ...and calling .json() on the response to return data
            .subscribe((res: Response) => {
                var payload = res.json();
                var authorization = res.headers.get('Authorization');
                var contentType = res.headers.get('Content-Type');                                
                console.log(payload, contentType, authorization)
            });            
    }
```

**Header Helper**

```
getHeaders(isSecureAPI: boolean) {
        let headers = new Headers({ 'Content-Type': 'application/json', 'Accept': 'application/json' });
        if (isSecureAPI) {
            headers.append('Authorization', 'GetFromSession');
            headers.append('X-UserID', 'GetFromSession');
        }
        return headers;
    }
```

**Fiddler track:**

[image]

**Angular Console Output**
[image]

So anyone can guide me what I am possibly doing wrong?

Comment: check the headers that might be not allowed by the server.

Comment: @Roman I am working on client side so could you please guide, How I can check on service side?

Comment: It's not possible without server side.

Comment: I don't know why It has been down voted and If anyone feel so, could you please atlist let me know the reason, which might guide me some right direction. Thanks :)

Comment: @RomanC As you can see in Fiddler screenshot we are getting list of allowed headers by the server, Which contains Authorization as well.

Comment: @Roman, we have allowed from server side already.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Header was allowed but not exposed on CORS server however adding  **headers.add("Access-Control-Expose-Headers", "Authorization, X-Custom");**  on server did the job :)

Comment: this did the job for me

Answer (score 2):

I've been trying to find a solution and came across [this](http://datawalke.com/c/webapi-owin-cors-and-custom-headers/)

Let's say I'm using the [Microsoft Cors WebAPI 2 Nuget package](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dn532203.aspx), and I have the following global configuration in my WebApiConfig.cs:

```
...
var corsAttr = new EnableCorsAttribute("http://localhost:4200", "*", "*");
config.EnableCors(corsAttr);
...
```

The EnableCorsAttribute constructor accepts a 4th string parameter to globally allow any additional headers:

```
var corsAttr = new EnableCorsAttribute("http://localhost:4200", "*", "*", "X-Foo, X-Bar, X-Baz");
```

Comment: Afaik browsers do not generally support a wildcard for the Access-Control-Expose-Headers

Comment: Did some further research @ErikAlsmyr - is this what you were referring to? (Under the Compatibility notes section) https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Access-Control-Expose-Headers