# Not able to read all the headers in response in angular 2

Tags: angular, http-headers

I have a function that downloads the file from server.

```
private _downloadFromUrl(url: string, fileName = "download.bin"): Observable<any> {
    const _response$ = new Subject<any>();

    this.http.get<Blob>(url, {
        observe: "response",
        responseType: "blob" as "json"
    })
        .subscribe(
            (response: any) => {
                console.log(" response.headers", response.headers);
                saveAs(response, fileName);
                _response$.next(true);
                _response$.complete();
            },
            (err) => {
                _response$.error(err);
                _response$.complete();
            }
        );
    return _response$;
}
```

I am unable to read all the response headers. I want to read file name.

this is what i get in `response.headers.keys()`

```
["cache-control", "content-length", "content-type", "expires", "pragma"]
```

but in browser these headers are present

```
ACCESS_CONTROL_EXPOSE_HEADERS: CONTENT_DISPOSITION 
CONTENT_DISPOSITION: abc.xml 
x-filename: abc.xml
```

is present in my response headers.

but if i try `response.headers.get("CONTENT_DISPOSITION")` or `response.headers.get("x-filename")` or `response.headers.get("CONTENT-DISPOSITION")` it returns `null`

Comment: Try: `response.headers._headers.get("CONTENT_DISPOSITION")`

Comment: `response.headers._headers` is undefined

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to get custom response header in angular 2?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42063685/how-to-get-custom-response-header-in-angular-2)