# Angular can't read http response header from nestjs

Tags: node.js, angular, nestjs

I am using nestjs as a back end restAPI
when I do a login request I send the JWT token to a custom header called 'x-auth'
I can receive it on Postman header response
[PostMan Respoese](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7ZUhA.png)

but in angular i cant read any headers while receiving the response
and here is the response logged to the console
[Response To Console](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qBKeE.png)

my backend controller

```
@Post('login')
  public async userLogin(@Body() body: CreateUserDto, @Res() res: Response) {
    const token = await this.usersService.userLogin(body);
    return res.header({ 'x-auth': token }).send({ success: true }).status(200);
  }
```

and this is my angular auth service

```
const httpOption = {
  headers: new HttpHeaders({ 'Content-Type': 'application/json' }),
  observe: 'response' as 'response',
};
@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root',
})
export class AuthService {
  loginApi = `${environment.serverUrl}users/login`;

  constructor(private http: HttpClient) {}

  loginUser(login: any): Observable<any> {
    return this.http.post<any>(this.loginApi, login, httpOption);
  }
}
```

and my auth components

```
export class AuthComponent implements OnInit {

  subscription: Subscription;
  constructor(private service: AuthService, private router: Router) {}

  ngOnInit(): void {}

  onLogin(form: NgForm) {
    this.subscription = this.service.loginUser(form.value).subscribe((res) => {
      console.log(res);
    });
  }
}
```

Comment: A quick search showed this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42063685/how-to-get-custom-response-header-in-angular-2

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to get custom response header in angular 2?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42063685/how-to-get-custom-response-header-in-angular-2)

Comment: I tried it but didn't work too